# make 2 consecutive moves in html

Tags: html, wordpress

From a certain page in my WordPress website I want to jump to another page then to a specific section in that page. I want to do that in one click on a text "click here".
how can I do that?

Comment: With just a short research you would have found your answer.

Comment: I guess you did not understand the question. I saw those answers and they are not what I need.

Comment: We completely understand the question. You didn't understand the answers.